# Implementation of Mapping a single key to multiple values using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of tag_ids configured with the test_id_val in a table.I retrieve the Data using the following query

```
Select test_id_val , tag_id from p_details
```

For a straightforward case i would rather use a hash map to store key value pair and retrieve the data,But in my case the test_id_val can accept null values

For ex consider the following structure :

```
 1. APP TR202 
 2. APP TR204 
 3. APP TR205 
 4.NULL TR206 
 5.NULL TR207 
 6.NULL SM504 
 7.NULL SM505
```

So i will be having a list of tag_ids values to map to a test_id key which can either be null or contain values.My requirement is to map the test_id key to the list of tag_ids

Is there a specific way to do this?

Thanks for the help and time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using some implementation of `com.google.common.collect.Multimap`.

You can put multiple values associated with one key and then retrieve them as a collection with the `map.get(key)` method. In your case:

```
Multimap<String, String> mmap = HashMultimap.create();

mmap.put("APP", "TR202");
mmap.put("APP", "TR204");
mmap.put("APP", "TR205");
mmap.put(null, "TR206");
mmap.put(null, "TR207");
mmap.put(null, "SM504");
mmap.put(null, "SM505");

for (String key : mmap.keySet()) {
  for (String value : mmap.get(key)) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
null: SM505
null: SM504
null: TR207
null: TR206
APP: TR202
APP: TR205
APP: TR204
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` to store the `test_id_val`. Then in `HashMap`, store `tag_id` as a key and index of ArrayList to `test_id_val` as a value of `HashMap`. ArrayList allows a null value so you can easily store the null value of specific `tag_id`. Like this..

```
KEY     VALUE               ArrayList
TR202     1                 1-->  APP 
TR204     2                 2-->  APP 
TR205     3                 3-->  APP 
TR206     4                 4-->  NULL 
TR207     5                 5-->  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider if this really is the best database schema design you have, but if you choose to stick with it, create a wrapper class for `test_id_val` in which you specify if you really mean `null` via a `boolean`:

```
private class TestIdVal {
    String test_id_val;
    boolean isNull;
}
```

You can then instantiate `new TestIdVal()` objects to use as keys for the map. I don't recommend using a list of `tag_id` as the key, as that doesn't seem to mirror your schema correctly. It seems that you're trying to do test_id_val => List of tag_id.